# Flutter int counter... adding a range

Tags: flutter, counter

I have an App made with flutter that when a button is pressed it increments a counter by 1. I would like to make the counter go to 10 and then simply start at 0 again. Is this possible?

this is code for the onPressed:

```
 RaisedButton(
   splashColor: Colors.blueAccent[700],
   child: Text(
          '+ Hit',
     style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
    ),
    color: Colors.lightBlue[100],
    onPressed: _incrementCounter,
  ),

and the _incrementCounter section of code: (I am storing the value in shared prefs)

    _incrementCounter() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
    counter = (prefs.getInt('counter') ?? 0) + 1;
    prefs.setInt('counter', counter);
    });
   }
```

How do i add the condition to start again when reaching 10??

Thanks to all

Comment: Yes. Show what code you have so far so that readers have something to work with, to suggest how to implement the requested change. Btw, it's simple; maybe search _modulo_.

Answer (score 0):

Add a condition on the onTap function of the button, where when counter > 10 then counter = 0

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this in your function which is triggered on button click

```
void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      if (_counter == 10) {
        _counter = 0;
      } else {
        _counter++;
      }
    });
}
```

_counter represents the variable which is holding count value

Answer (score 0):

Sure it is.
you have to use an if satement which sets the counter back to zero once it has reached 10.

[Run on DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/b6409e10de32b280b8938aa75364fa7b)

```dart
// Copyright (c) 2019, the Dart project authors.  Please see the AUTHORS file
// for details. All rights reserved. Use of this source code is governed by a
// BSD-style license that can be found in the LICENSE file.

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      // Your IF statement wgich defines when the counter goes back to zero
      if(_counter>=10) {
        _counter=0;
      } else {
        _counter++;
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It won't work, you said >= 10 which means it will never reach 10 and go to 0 from 9.

Comment: Thank you for your answers people, very much appreciated, Howeer: I am storing counter in Shared prefs and so i am first _loadCounter then i am _incrementCounter.  How do i set the IF function to work with the shared prefs?

Comment: @MattSillett Just put the `if` it in your current function, between getting the current value and setting the next one.

Answer (score 0):

many thanks. This is now solved, apologies taken so long to post answer but have had to isolate (without laptop :( ),

Here is the code that works. Thanks again to the above contributions. You really helped

```
 _incrementCounter() async {
 SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
 setState(() {
   if (counter >= 10) {
     counter = 1;
   } else {
     prefs.setInt('counter', counter++);
   }
   prefs.setInt('counter', counter);
 });
```

}